# 5:1 Mux design for a common bus system

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, bus, register

I am tinkering with logic gates preparing for an exam and came across a question that states the following

> Construct a common bus system for six registers where each register has five bits.

the expression I got from the truth table was

`S2'S1'S0'D0 + S2'S1'S0D1 + S2'S1S0'D2 + S2'S1S0D3 + S2S1'S0'D4`

where `'` is the complement

the circuit that I constructed looks like

[image: 5to1Mux]

Assuming the design is right, my question is that I have 6 registers and this design relies on one of the (D0-D4) being 1 and the rest is not important.  How can this be used to reference 6 registers?  What am I missing because I can't grasp the idea behind it?

The registers and their bits

- first `10000`
- second `01000`
- third `00100`
- fourth `00010`
- fifth `00001`

As far as I can tell there is not sixth register with only one bit being 1

- bottom input bit is the enable
- top three bits are the selectors
- left 5 bits are the register bits

Comment: Observations: 1) buses have multiple participants, I expect *multiple signal sources for a single line* (or pair of lines) *in at least one direction*. 2) *register*s have inputs, too. 3) *six* registers, not five.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I interpret the exam question.  You want the bus to select 1 of the 6 registers.  Conceptually, this is a 6:1 mux, where the mux output is a 5-bit data bus.  There are 6 data inputs to the mux, each of which is 5 bits wide.  You have 6 5-bit registers, for a total of 30 register bits.

The 6:1 mux requires 3 select bits, as you have chosen.

The diagram you created represents one data bit from each of 5 registers.  D0 is from the 1st register, D1 is from the 2nd, ... D4 is from the 5th.  Now you need to add a 6th term: `S2S1'S0D5`.  Your OR gate needs a 6th input, and you need to add a 6th AND gate for D5.

```
S2'S1'S0'D0 + S2'S1'S0D1 + S2'S1S0'D2 + S2'S1S0D3 + S2S1'S0'D4 + S2S1'S0D5
```

To handle all 5 bits of the output, you need to replicate your diagram 5 times.

Since you have 6 registers, you need D5 to be a bit from the 6th register.

Comment: but if I add D5 this would result in a 6-bit register which does not match the question description of 5-bit register

Comment: @WeedCookie: Re-read my answer carefully.  D5 is not a 6-bit register.  D5 is one bit in the 6th register.  You have a total of 30 data bits: 5 bits each in 6 registers.  D0, D1, etc. are bits in _different_ registers.

Comment: If I understood your explaination correctly this means that I have to follow these equations 

`Number of multiplexers needed = Number of bits in each register`

`Number of inputs in each multiplexers needed = Total Number of registers.`

resulting in 5 multiplexers each having 6 inputs and a common bus that has 5 output lines, right?

Comment: @WeedCookie; Yes!  Exactly!